# Source for quote from Vilna Gaon

Tags: sources-mekorot, kavana-concentration, vilna-gaon

In a torah.org *[dvar torah](https://torah.org/torah-portion/ravfrand-5781-terumah/)* from Rabbi Frand, he quotes a 'famous saying from the Gaon of Vilna'.

> There is a famous saying from the Gaon of Vilna: If the wood used in
> the ax handle used to chop down trees used to build a Beis HaKeneses
> came from a tree planted by a Shomer Shabbos Jew, people would never
> recite a prayer without Kavannah (intense devotion) in that shul.

Where can I find the original source for this quote?